# How to make sure content stays below when using React-Router and Outlet

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

So I have an app that has 2 pages present, one of them is the main screen, let's call it Main, (the default page, or rather the page that is supposed to show when all other pages are loaded, using Outlet component from react-router), whilst the other is a different page, called Other.

Now I have some text present at the bottom of my page on the main screen, however, if the text within the Other screen exceeds the length of the page, the text which is supposed to be present at the bottom of the page actually overlaps with text from the Other screen.

[image: Example]

This is an example of what I mean, the bar, phone number and email are meant to be there regardless of what page I actually select and should be in theory pushed down, but they are overlapping

Code: This is the main file:

```js
import './App.css';
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" id="outer-container">
      <Sidebar />

      <hr id='line' />
      <p id='p'>Phone: +1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX</p>
      <p id='p2'>Email: XXXXX@XXXXX.com</p>
      <p id='p3'>Follow me on:</p>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Its corresponding CSS file is:

```css
hr#line {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100vw - 46px);
    height: 0px;
    left: 23px;
    right: 23px;
    top: 80vh;

    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

p#p {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 34px;
    left: 19px;
    top: 85vh;

    font-family: 'PT Serif';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 95.52%;

    /* or 12px */

    color: #000000;
}

p#p2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 34px;
    left: calc(50vw - 10vw);
    top: 85vh;

    font-family: 'PT Serif';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 95.52%;

    /* or 12px */

    color: #000000;
}

p#p3 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 34px;
    left: calc(100vw - 20vw);
    top: 85vh;

    font-family: 'PT Serif';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 95.52%;

    color: #000000;
}
```

For the "Other File" that I described, we have:

```js
export default function About() {
    return (
      <div className="about-container">
        <div className='peach-gradient color-block-5 mb-3 mx-auto rounded-circle z-depth-1 upper-about'>
          <h2>About</h2>
        </div>
          <p>
The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
1914 translation by H. Rackham

"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC

"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
1914 translation by H. Rackham

"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This file has no CSS

Comment: So basically you want that text you are talking about to behave as a footer?

Comment: Pretty much yes, but while behaving well as Outlet from react-router as well

Comment: Please share the code you are using, we can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. See [mcve]. This is probably more a CSS/UI layout issue than it is a `react-router` (*or even `react`*) issue.

Comment: I guess you could use a `div` with `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column` that wraps another `div` with `flex: 1` (the one containing the text / content you want to keep on top). That way the main content should take all the vertical remaining space regardless of the size of the actual content, pushing down your "footer". Not sure if this is exactly what you need tho.

Comment: @DrewReese I added in the code

Comment: @DrewReese It does partially. In that case the footer is fixed to be seen on screen, I was wondering of a way to push the footer down, even possibly off screen if the text was long enough. However, it still works well enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question and request correctly, it seems you want a "footer" that "sticks" to the bottom of the page until there's enough content to push it down. For this I suggest a refactor of component containers and improved CSS styling.

Example:

Create a footer component:

```
const Footer = () => (
  <footer>
    <hr />
    <div className="row">
      <p>Phone: +1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX</p>
      <p>Email: XXXXX@XXXXX.com</p>
      <p>Follow me on:</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
);
```

Update the app container component:

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="outer-container">
    ...
    <div className="page">
      <Outlet />
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
);
```

CSS

```
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.page {
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

footer .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

hr {
  height: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

footer p {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 34px;

  font-family: 'PT Serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 95.52%;
  
  color: #000000;
}
```

### How it works

The `"outer-container"` div is sit to have a minimum height that fills the screen while the nested `"page"` div wraps the `Outlet` and grows to fill available space. When there is enough content in the `"page"` div it will overflow and push the footer element down.

[image: Edit how-to-make-sure-content-stays-below-when-using-react-router-and-outlet]

Test in sandbox by adjusting the view width to make the lorem ipsum text of the About page grow/shrink height-wise to push the footer down or stick to the bottom.